# flexible type error - python dict to sparse matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, flexible-type

I'm very unfamiliar with a 'flexible' type, and was hoping to gain insights into why my below hits this type of error when I thought I was working with basic string elements.

I have a large dictionary `user_artist_dict` with entries as follows:

```
{'a': ['the beatles','tool','orbital','the smiths','paul oakenfold'], 
 'b': ['madlib','sigur r\xc3\xb3s','the acorn','feist','sera cahoone'], ...}
```

onto key value c, d, etc.

Here's my code:

```
mat = sp.dok_matrix((74617, 121344), dtype=np.unicode_)
for user_id, artist_ids in user_artist_dict.items():
    mat[user_id, artist_ids] = 1
```

I'm thrown `TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type` but is it cuz I'm using Python2?

Comment: You can't use strings as keys or indices of sparse matrices.

Comment: @hpaulj what matrix type would you recommend if i wanted to add to each dictionary the number of plays per artist, as in {'a': [{'the beatles': 150, 'tool': 275]} and so on?